# Rails Testing link found with rspec/Capybara but form not generated on click

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara

My intention with this test is to find a Create link -- one of many hence I'm using `first` -- and then fill out a form that is generated with javascript upon clicking that link.  Despite successfully finding the Create link and calling click on it, the form is not generated.

```
require 'spec_helper'
include Warden::Test::Helpers
Warden.test_mode!

describe "user log in" do
  it "allows an existing user to sign in" do 
    visit "/users/sign_in"

    fill_in "Login", with: "Kevin"
    fill_in "Password", with: "abcdef"

    visit "/students/2/schedule"
    first(:link, 'Create').click

    within '#session_minutes' do
     find("option[value='60']").click
    end

  end
end
```

Is this possibly a javascript/rspec issue?  After implementing phantomjs and poltergeist to generate JS actions on a headless browser I could not simulate the on hover effect needed to access the Create link so I'm not sure which testing method to pursue to ameliorate my situation.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a driver that supports javascript for that, capybara's default driver does not.

You can find the documentation for drivers [here](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara#drivers).

I prefer poltergeist because it's totally headless (doesn't require an actual browser) and so can run in a headless vagrant box.  Selenium requires almost no setup if you already have Firefox installed.

Comment: I've implemented phantom js but now the problem is I can't simulate an on hover effect -- there seems to be quite a large number of requests for this feature within poltergeist.  Has it been implemented?

Comment: Poltergeist does support `find('selector').hover` and according to its [specs](https://github.com/teampoltergeist/poltergeist/blob/master/spec/integration/session_spec.rb) it hovers before a click.  A css `:hover` pseudoclass is not the same as a `mouseover` event, though.

Answer (score 0):

To solve my issue I went with using poltergeist and phantomjs and then using the `mouseover` action as follows

```
require 'spec_helper'
include Warden::Test::Helpers
Warden.test_mode!

describe "user log in" do
  it "allows an existing user to sign in" do 
    visit "/users/sign_in"

    fill_in "Login", with: "Kevin"
    fill_in "Password", with: "abcdef"

    visit "/students/2/schedule"
    first('.open').trigger('mouseover')

  end
end
```